Reference error when trying to build nextjs project which uses Lottie animation
So I have a nextjs website that uses a Lottie animation in the hero component. When trying to build my nextjs project using npm run build, I run into this error:

Collecting page data  ...ReferenceError: document is not defined
at createTag (/Users/dayemsaeed/Downloads/seher-landing-page/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:30:5)
at /Users/dayemsaeed/Downloads/seher-landing-page/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:1316:20
at /Users/dayemsaeed/Downloads/seher-landing-page/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:1323:6
at /Users/dayemsaeed/Downloads/seher-landing-page/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:1540:4
at /Users/dayemsaeed/Downloads/seher-landing-page/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:2:83
at Object. (/Users/dayemsaeed/Downloads/seher-landing-page/node_modules/lottie-web/build/player/lottie.js:5:3)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)


Build error occurred
Error: Failed to collect page data for /
at /Users/dayemsaeed/Downloads/seher-landing-page/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:1268:15 {
type: 'Error'
}

This is how I'm using the Lottie animation:
import Lottie from "lottie-react";
import catAnimation from "../../../../../public/lotties/cat-animation.json";
return (
    <div className="sm:w-[500px] aspect-square">
         <Lottie animationData={catAnimation} loop={true} />
    </div>
);

I’ve tried using Lottie.loadAnimation() as well but that just doesn’t get recognized as a valid method. I’d really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on what the issue is here
